# Is there any way ,we authenticate the xdmp:http-put function inside the schedule task without using authentication options?

Tags: rest, http, scheduled-tasks, marklogic

Is there any way ,we will get the authentication of schedule task to authenticate the xdmp:http-put function inside the schedule task.
For example :=
Schedule task run a xqyfile in every minutes ,and that file contains a http:put method to call a rest service.

```
let $url  := 
fn:concat('http://',xdmp:hostname($host),':',$PORT,'/v1/resources/example')   
        return
                xdmp:http-put($url,
                    <options xmlns="xdmp:http"> 
                        <data>{
                           xdmp:quote($data)
                       }</data> 
                 </options>
```

where $port is the rest service port ,$host is the host in cluster
Is this possible to get the autentication from schedule task and pass it, to xdmp:http-put method.This is require ,because password is environment dependent,we will not know the password.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to invoke an endpoint without authentication, you could configure an appserver with [Application Level](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/authentication#id_60432) authentication and set a default user. There are obvious security considerations, so you might have a specific appserver setup for this purpose and configure minimal roles and permissions for that default user.

Another option would be to use [Secure Credentials](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/secure-credentials) to store the authentication information securely in the Security database.

> `<credential-id>`
> The credential id to use for authentication. This is the preferred way of providing authentication credentials because they are stored securely in the security database. When a credential id is specified, the other authentication information fields should be left empty and will be ignored. For details on obtaining a credential id, see the Usage Notes, below.

```
import module namespace sec = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security" at "/MarkLogic/security.xqy";
xdmp:invoke-function(function() {
  sec:create-credential("my-secure-credential", "a secure credential", 
     "myUsername", "myPassword", 
     (), (), fn:false(), 
     sec:uri-credential-target(".*/v1/resources/example.*", "digest"), 
     xdmp:permission("rest-writer", "execute")
   )
 },
 <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
   <database>{xdmp:database("Security")}</database>
 </options>
)
```

Then leverage those credentials in the options of the `xdmp:http-put`.

```
let $url  := fn:concat('http://',xdmp:hostname($host),':',$PORT,'/v1/resources/example')   
return
  xdmp:http-put($url,
                <options xmlns="xdmp:http"> 
                  <data>{xdmp:quote($data)}</data>
                  <credential-id>{xdmp:credential-id("my-secure-credential")}</credential-id> 
                </options>)
```

That way, you can update the credentials on each system and avoid hard-coding authentication information in the code.

If the endpoint that you are trying to invoke is a MarkLogic REST endpoint, then rather than invoking via HTTP, you could have your scheduled task module import the REST module and invoke it's get or post method:

```
import module namespace m = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/example" 
  at "/marklogic.rest.resource/example/assets/resource.xqy";
let $context := map:map()
let $params := map:map()
let $input := ()
return m:post($context,$params, $input)
```